# iPhoneのアプリを実機で動作するととても遅くなります

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

iPhoneのアプリを作っています。
主に画像をカメラを使ってやカメラロールから選択して、コレクションビューに表示することのできるようなアプリを作っているのですが、実機で動かしてみると遅くなってしまいます。

どのような時に遅くなるのかというと、カメラを使って、またはカメラロールから画像を選択してコレクションビューに表示する時などコレクションビューの写真が並んでいる画面に戻る時に遅くなっているように感じます。

iOSシュミレータでは実機よりは早いのですがそれでも少し遅いように感じます。

これはコードに問題があるのでしょうか、初めてのアプリ開発の実機での操作でわからず困っています。
なにか考えられることはありませんか。どなたかよろしくお願いします。

[image: メモリの状況です]

コレクションビューの画面に戻ってくる時がHighの294MBでした。一連の遅くなる原因はメモリの問題だということでしょうか。

Comment: まずはXcodeでメモリー使用量もしくはCPU使用率のグラフを見て、どのタイミングで値が増大するか確認してください。特定の操作でメモリー使用量が増大するのであれば、そのオブジェクトに対する解放処理が漏れているのだと判断できます。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。僕はオブジェクトを解放しなくてはいけないということでしょうか。

Comment: 戻ってくると遅くなっているということでしたので、まずはどのタイミングで負荷がかかっているのか計測して確認するということです。画面遷移の前後で重くなるとのことでしたのでメモリリークを疑いましたが、184MBという数字を見ると単純にメモリを使い過ぎているだけのような気もします。